# Why do I get this error "TypeError: canvas.toDataURL is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, canvas, todataurl

I'm trying to generate an image of a canvas generated by angular-charts, but I keep getting this error.
Is there something wrong with my code?

here is the canvas:

```
<canvas id="radar" class="chart chart-radar radarCanvas"
          chart-data="radarData" chart-labels="radarLabels" chart-legend="true" chart-series="radarLegends"
          chart-options="options">
        </canvas>
```

and here is the function:

```
$('.radarCanvas').each(function () {
            var canvas=this;
            img=JSON.stringify(canvas.toDataURL());

});
```

Comment: What happen if you replace `this` with `$("#radar")` ?

Comment: Its working..Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/ou4jv8oe/

Comment: @Ofiris : it works with the Id. But the problem is I have many canvas like that, and $("#radar") only picks the first one.

Comment: @RayonDabre : you are right, it's working, but somehow it doesn't work for me. Maybe because the canvas is manipulated by angular-charts?!

Comment: @younessofiane, Incomplete question will never get appropriate answer..Try providing fiddle for the same...

Comment: @RayonDabre I made a plunker for my problem, and after a few tries I found out the problem: in one graph, I wasn't using only the canvas, but I was providing a <h4> element with it, and that's why it didn't work.
Thank you for your help.
http://plnkr.co/edit/PkZiqYynzQXehbe6p1eH?p=preview

Comment: @younessofiane, ;) Enjoy coding :)